# Why does Mark Zuckerberg cover his headphone jack with tape?

Tags: hardware, facebook

I can understand covering the camera or microphone but why the audio jack?

Mark Zuckerberg have shared a photo to his Facebook account and celebrating the growing user base of Instagram which is owned by Facebook.

[image]

[image]

Image Source - fb

Comment: Are you sure it's covering the jack? Perhaps it's covering the microphone?

Comment: [Constructive subjective questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”; tend to have long, not short, answers; have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone; invite sharing experiences over opinions; insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references; **are more than just mindless social fun**

Comment: @techraf That is your opinion. I will not update my question. My question is simple and clear.

Comment: Maybe because of a personal security policy involving disabling and blocking any uneeded information input and output systems on a systematic basis no matter if there a risk currently identified or not. Or maybe he broke it on that morning when he was not fully awake and hadn't the time yet to bring to Apple geniuses for repair. One can guess anything!

Comment: I think that's a Macbook Air? The microphone is next to the headphone jack - [look here](http://forums.macrumors.com/attachments/image-jpg.450564/). So yes, he's covering the microphone, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back Yes, I fully agree, your question is simple and clear. Does it inspire answers as defined in the Help Center?

Comment: Business Insider noticed [too](http://www.businessinsider.com/zuckerberg-tapes-laptop-camera-2016-6?utm_content=buffer95204&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer&IR=T)

Comment: BTW, covering a mike hole doesn't really disable the mike, merely serves to muffle the sound. And if the sound's able to resonate the device case, you can actually, from experience, hear any near conversions quite well as it proves out to only be a distance muffler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a useless question but still interesting one :)

and that is not audio jack
[image]

He is a security freak like me, not real freak but there are some people who really care for their device security and of course a CEO will have some serious data inside his laptop, I am sure you understand that covering mic and cam is so that even an un-authorised access to his cam will not reveal his face or sounds of the surroundings. Mark really cares for security, like he doesn't want to leave a single loop hole or any kind of vulnerability in his system that's why he even released a sort of security contest where you will get awarded with money if you can find a vulnerability in his Facebook System.

As I did search for his laptop, I found about the laptop, it's MacBook Air (and I precisely got the image of left side of that laptop) and you can see here in the image that before headphone's jack comes an inbuilt microphone, and of course it's not a microphone jack, it's an actual inbuilt microphone as jacks aren't that small. So you see, he is again covering his microphone so that hackers can't access sound even if they got access to his Macbook's microphone

**so in summary:-**

He covered his top cam and then covered his left side inbuilt mic so that no un authorised access can harm him, basically doing the best to stay from hackers and getting hacked or any kind of personal audio/video from getting hacked & released. So even if hackers hack his laptop successfully, they won't be able to use his webcam or mic